# LibVLC.NET in GTK#

Tags: c#, vlc, gtk#, libvlc

I use [LibVLC.NET](http://libvlcnet.codeplex.com/) wrapper in GTK#. And I have already played video using this example:

```
LibVLCLibrary library = LibVLCLibrary.Load(null);
IntPtr inst, mp, m;

inst = library.libvlc_new();                                      // Load the VLC engine 
m = library.libvlc_media_new_location(inst, "path/to/your/file"); // Create a new item 
mp = library.libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);               // Create a media player playing environement 
library.libvlc_media_release(m);                                  // No need to keep the media now 
library.libvlc_media_player_play(mp);                             // play the media_player 
Thread.Sleep(10000);                                              // Let it play a bit 
library.libvlc_media_player_stop(mp);                             // Stop playing 
library.libvlc_media_player_release(mp);                          // Free the media_player 
library.libvlc_release(inst);

LibVLCLibrary.Free(library);
```

But video playing in another new window, now i need to set window or (better) container in GTK# which will play video. How should I do this?

**Update:**
I found this function in LibVLC.NET:

```
 //==========================================================================
// void libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks (libvlc_media_player_t *mp, libvlc_video_format_cb setup, libvlc_video_cleanup_cb cleanup)

//==========================================================================
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate uint libvlc_video_format_cb(ref IntPtr opaque, ref uint chroma, ref uint width, ref uint height, ref uint pitches, ref uint lines);

//==========================================================================
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void libvlc_video_cleanup_cb(IntPtr opaque);

//==========================================================================
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks_signature(IntPtr mp, libvlc_video_format_cb setup, libvlc_video_cleanup_cb cleanup);

//==========================================================================
private readonly libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks_signature m_libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks;

//==========================================================================
public void libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks(IntPtr mp, libvlc_video_format_cb setup, libvlc_video_cleanup_cb cleanup)
{
  VerifyAccess();

  m_libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks(mp, setup, cleanup);
}

/*
  void libvlc_media_player_set_nsobject (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi, void *drawable)
  void * libvlc_media_player_get_nsobject (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi)
  void libvlc_media_player_set_agl (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi, uint32_t drawable)
  uint32_t libvlc_media_player_get_agl (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi)
  void libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi, uint32_t drawable)
  uint32_t libvlc_media_player_get_xwindow (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi)
  void libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi, void *drawable)
  void * libvlc_media_player_get_hwnd (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi)
*/
```

In the comments there is mention of libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd (), may be this function somehow replace it or give access to the same opportunities as libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd ()?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the platform, you need to call libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow (Linux), libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd (Windows), or libvlc_media_player_set_nsobject (OSX).

The second parameter is an integer that is the handle to the native component that you want to embed the video.

Toolkits like GTK/GTK# should provide a method on the component that enables you to get this window handler.

For example this C# code can be used to get the needed window handle from a GTK Widget

```
private static Int32 Wid(Widget widget) {
    IntPtr windowPtr = gtk_widget_get_window(widget.Handle);
    if(windowPtr != IntPtr.Zero) {
        IntPtr xidPtr = gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid(windowPtr);
        if(xidPtr != IntPtr.Zero) {
            return xidPtr.ToInt32();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You only need to do this once after you create your media player and the native component, you do not need to do it each time you play media.

Comment: I think it will help, but I haven't this functions in LibVLC.NET.

Comment: If that's the case, then I don't think you can use that library the way I described. It looks like the example provided by that project renders the video by using a bitmap, meaning it must be using the video callbacks. This doesn't help: http://libvlcnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/LibVLC.NET.Presentation/ ?

Comment: How to use private static Int32 Wid(Widget widget) in GTK#?
Or how to get xid in GTK#?